# Ввожу mysite.ru - перебрасывает на вирусный сайт

Tags: вирусы

Написала на php записную книгу, все работает на денвере. Все вроде нормально работало, записи добавлялись и удалялись без проблем.

Но теперь когда я нажимаю на ссылку удалить запись, меня перебрасывает на сайт keramzit.ru. Та же история, если я в браузер в адресной строке ввожу mysite.ru.

Уже 3 антивирусами проверяла, не помогло. И такая ситуация во всех браузерах.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66049/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Домен mysite.ru - это самый настоящий синоним для keramzit.ru. Можно предположить что у них один владелец.

```
$ curl -I mysite.ru
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 11 Sep 2017 06:04:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Location: https://keramzit.ru/
```

Никакого криминала тут нет. У них даже одинаковые DNS сервера.

```
$ dig +short ns keramzit.ru
ns3.firstbytedns.com.
ns2.firstbytedns.com.
ns1.firstbytedns.com.

$ dig +short ns mysite.ru
ns2.firstbytedns.com.
ns1.firstbytedns.com.
ns3.firstbytedns.com.
```

Попробуйте использовать не mysite.ru, а настоящее имя вашего сайта. Если настоящего имени ещё нет, то используйте имя несуществующего домена, прописав его в `hosts` или поддомен вида `mysite.vcap.me` или подобный, заведомо указывающий на localhost.

Для примеров в коде или вопросах используйте [зарезервированные специально для использования в примерах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2) доменные имена **example.com** и **test.ru**.

Те же рекомендации относятся к site.ru - это домен какого-то частного лица.

Домен `.dev` принадлежит Google, не пользуйтесь им для тестовых целей.