# SslStream и HTTP: ноль доступных байт для чтения

Tags: c#, авторизация, ssl, https

```
IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];

Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 443));
NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

byte[] responseData;
string sessionId = "";

// Authorization.

StringBuilder sbRequest = new StringBuilder();
string formData = string.Format("login_login={0}&login_password={1}", login, password);
sbRequest.Append("POST https://test.ru/login HTTP/1.1\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Host: " + host + "\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Connection: keep-alive\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Content-Length: " + formData.Length + "\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Origin: https://test.ru\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Referer: https://test.ru/login-page\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("\r\n" + formData);
sslStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbRequest.ToString()));
sslStream.Flush();

string response = "";
while (true) {
    responseData = new byte[1024];
    if (sslStream.Read(responseData, 0, responseData.Length) == 0) break;
    response += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseData);
}
Console.Write(response);
Console.WriteLine("\n".PadRight(90, '-') + "\n");
if (response.Contains("sessionid="))
    sessionId = response.Substring(response.IndexOf("sessionid=") - 10, 32);

// Main page request.

sbRequest = new StringBuilder();
sbRequest.Append("GET https://test.ru/personal-area/ HTTP/1.1\r\n");
sbRequest.Append("Host: " + host + "\r\n");
sbRequest.Append($"Cookie: sessionid={sessionId}\r\n\r\n");
sslStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbRequest.ToString()));
sslStream.Flush();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

while (true) {
    responseData = new byte[1024];
    if (sslStream.Read(responseData, 0, responseData.Length) == 0) break;
    Console.WriteLine(responseData.Length);
    Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseData));
}
Console.WriteLine("\n".PadRight(90, '-') + "\n");

sslStream.Dispose();

Console.WriteLine("\nThe end!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на некотором ресурсе "test.ru". В результате какой то ошибки второй запрос просто не выполняется. От сервера, как говориться, ни ответа ни привета (0 доступных байт для чтения сколько не жди). На первый запрос ответ даётся адекватный: `{"success": true,"redirect": "/"}`.

Могу предоставить так же расшифровку пакетов обмена данными между моим браузером и сервером этого сайта в момент авторизации:

```
------------------------------------------------
REQUEST1
------------------------------------------------
POST https://test.ru/login HTTP/1.1
Host: [HOST]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 48
Accept: */*
Origin: https://test.ru
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Referer: https://test.ru/login-page
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: sessionid=[LASTSESSIONID]

login_login=[LOGIN]&login_password=[PASSWORD]
------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE1
------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 10:54:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: sessionid=[SESSIONID]; httponly; Path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Content-Length: 33

{"success": true,"redirect": "/"}
------------------------------------------------
REQUEST2
------------------------------------------------
GET https://test.ru/ HTTP/1.1
Host: [HOST]
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://test.ru/login-page
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: sessionid=[SESSIONID]

------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE2
------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 10:54:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Location: personal-area
Set-Cookie: sessionid=[SESSIONID]; httponly; Path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Content-Length: 0

------------------------------------------------
REQUEST3
------------------------------------------------
GET https://test.ru/personal-area/ HTTP/1.1
Host: [HOST]
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Referer: https://test.ru/login-page
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: sessionid=[SESSIONID]

------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE3
------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2018 10:54:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: sessionid=[SESSIONID]; httponly; Path=/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Content-Length: 273380

[HTMLPAGECODE]
...
```

Comment: Какой-нибудь [flush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.security.sslstream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) случайно не забыт?

Comment: Нет. Это не поможет

Comment: «Не поможет» вместо «не помогло» понимать как то, что вы даже не пробовали?)

Comment: Ну, вроде из лога запросов видно, что по https://site.ru/ 302-й редирект и грузить нужно personal-area. В чем именно проблема?

Comment: @SmInc Не. Нужно использовать именно SslStream и составление запросов "вручную".

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Грузить personal-area сразу? Может быть, но это проблемы не отменяет. Я же говорю, ответа от сервера не дождёшься.

Comment: @andeymal Ну конечно пробовал.

Comment: Cookie: sessionid=[SESSIONID] какую-то смысловую нагрузку несет?  В логе он используется, а в коде похоже нет.

Comment: Видимо это id сессии, который задаёт сервер. В коде я игнорировал передачу этого значения. Пробовал, конечно, и указывать id, но это не решило вопроса. Смысловой нагрузки наверное не несёт, там просто 32 байта символов.

Comment: Еще во втором запросе заголовок заканчивается на одинарный \r\n, а не двойной

Comment: Ну тоже не в этом дело. Ошибка остаётся

Comment: Ну я подправил код и внёс все предложенные изменения. Не знаю в чём проблема.

Comment: `site.ru`  -  это чужой сайт, не используйте его для тестов. Для тестов есть test.ru и example.com. [Иначе будет как здесь.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/716859/201364)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 доступных для чтения байт означает что с той стороны соединение было закрыто. После этого любые попытки чтения будут возвращать вам 0 байт. Предположу что сервер просто закрывает соединение  по тайм-ауту не дождавшись вашего второго запроса.

Ваш цикл чтения данных где вы ждете 0 байт - принципиально некорректен. Точнее, он был бы корректным если бы вы передали серверу заголовок `Connection: close` или если бы вы использовали протокол HTTP/1.0 без заголовка `Keep-alive`.

Если вы собираетесь отправить два запроса в одном соединении, вам все-таки придется искать конец первого ответа согласно принятым в HTTP правилам:

1. Сначала нужно читать блок заголовков пока не встретится два перевода строки.
2. В блоке заголовков следует найти заголовок Content-Length.
3. Если он присутствует - то вам надо прочитать после блока заголовков ровно указанное число байт содержимого, в противном случае надо читать до конца потока.

Comment: В каком смысле искать конец первого ответа? Я просто читаю всё подряд. Мне и не нужно разделять пакеты между собой. Я просто хочу видеть ответ сервера на второй запрос. Вопрос в том как его правильно сформировать. _Ваш цикл чтения данных где вы ждете 0 байт - принципиально некорректен._ - пример топорный, чисто ради тестирования.

Comment: @D.Stark проблема в том, что с таким циклом вы не успеваете отправить второй запрос раньше чем сервер оборвет соединение. Потому что вы явно дожидаетесь этого самого обрыва соединения.

Comment: @D.Stark чтобы успеть отправить второй запрос - вам надо начать это делать когда вы прочитаете ответ на первый. А для этого нужно определить границу первого ответа.

Comment: А Send/Receive-timeout не вариант?

Comment: @D.Stark нет. Тайм-ауты лишь разорвут соединение, только теперь уже с вашей стороны.

Comment: А ну да. Точно.

Comment: Что ж... Теперь ответ от сервера на второй запрос тоже приходит. Только немного не тот: https://pastebin.com/5JTUxhM4

Comment: Я пробовал отправлять запрос на адрес .../personal-area/ два раза подряд, а так же отправлять сначала на .../, а потом на .../personal-area/. Но это не меняет результата. Что можно сделать?

Comment: @D.Stark Вы шлете голый запрос без куков на сайт с авторизацией. Естественно, это не работает. Вас просто отфутболивает на страницу ввода логина и пароля.

Comment: Это решило мою проблему. Ну я сам уже конечно подумывал о передаче sessionid...

Comment: Хм. Что-то снова не так: https://pastebin.com/McQJZBSY

Comment: Молчит на последний запрос...

Comment: Хотя время до чтения кода станицы ".../personal-area/" 300 мс проходит. SessionId передаётся. Пробовал в Cookie ещё передать "sessionid=...; httponly; Path=/" но это не помогло.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Не знаете что не так?

Comment: @D.Stark Не знаю. Как уже сказано, руками реализовывать полноценный обмен по HTTPS сложно и не нужно. Если все же хотите, изучайте исходники WebClient в .NET и смотрите как это делать правильно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Если знаете чем помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828325/Ошибка-при-загрузке-страницы-входа-на-сайте

Answer (score 0):

[Вы столкнулись с проблемой молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) (или XY), которая заключается в том, что вы пишите запросы руками, при этом не следуя протоколу, не дожидаясь получения ответа сервера, как пишут в соседнем ответе, что происходит потому что вы не используете предназначенные для отправки запросов средства.

Лучшим вариантом было бы не писать руками запросы, а использовать какую-то готовую библиотеку типа `HttpClient`:

```
using System.Net.Http;

var client = new HttpClient();

// Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new [] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("text", "This is a block of text"),
});

// Get the response.
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
    "http://test.ru/example.json",
    requestContent);

// Get the response content.
HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

// Get the stream of the content.
using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
{
    // Write the output.
    Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
}
```

[Пример отсюда.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929013/making-a-curl-call-in-c-sharp)

Если продолжить писать запросы руками, то можно встретить много всего другого интересного. Например, изучить [как chunked разбирать](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Чтобы на это не слишком полезное дело время не тратить, лучше пользоваться готовыми инструментами. В них все готово и просчитано.

Comment: Если бы вы прочли комментарии к вопросу и первому ответу, то поняли бы, что задача составить именно запрос "руками". Это, ещё раз, чисто топорный пример для решения моей минизадачи. site.ru - не реальный сайт, а просто замена имени домена другого реального ресурса. Этот пример отчасти псевдокод, т.к. он в таком виде (с site.ru) работать не должен. Проблема на самом деле заключалась в превышении интервала ожидания запроса на сервере (слишком долго ответ на перый запрос обрабатывал). И, кстати, как вы можете использовать SslStream вместе с HttpWebRequest? Никак. В этом и соль...

Comment: Ну вопрос, как бы,уже решён. Это можно было понять из комментов.

Comment: @D.Stark Похоже вы не понимаете цели этого сайта. Здесь ответы пишут не столько чтобы помочь вам, а чтобы помочь другим людям, которые столкнутся с этой же проблемой.

Comment: Так задача - использовать SslStream. А решение - грамотное чтение ответа без задержки.

Comment: Ни то ни другое вы не предложили.

Comment: Но не беспокойтесь, ваш ответ никто не удаляет.

Comment: @D.Stark не то чтобы вы могли :)