# Ошибка при загрузке страницы входа на сайте

Tags: c#, https, tls

Пытаемся получить корректный ответ от веб-сервера:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 443));
NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream);
sslStream.ReadTimeout = -1;
sslStream.WriteTimeout = -1;
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

// Load login page.

sbRequest = new StringBuilder();
sbRequest.Append("GET /auth/login-page HTTP/1.1\r\n");
sbRequest.Append($"Host: {host}\r\n\r\n");
sslStream.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbRequest.ToString()));
sslStream.Flush();

// Read web-server response.

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

// (read the first 1024 bytes - all headers and the page beginning)
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
sslStream.Read(data, 0, 1024);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
```

Итог общения:

```
REQUEST:
--------------------------------------------------
GET /auth/login-page HTTP/1.1
Host: [host]

--------------------------------------------------

RESPONSE
--------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 17:35:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000

1f66
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta ...
```

Где, собственно, Content-Length? Что за "1f66"?..

Дабы проверить как это делает браузер (ведь у него же всё получается), посмотрел Fiddler'ом как сайт отвечает на его запросы:

```
REQUEST:
--------------------------------------------------
GET /auth/login-page HTTP/1.1
Host: [host]
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

--------------------------------------------------

RESPONSE:
--------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 16:59:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Content-Length: 8992

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta ...
```

Сделал точно такой же запрос из своей программы, но ответ пришёл ещё хуже:

```
REQUEST:
--------------------------------------------------
GET /auth/login-page HTTP/1.1
Host: [host]
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

--------------------------------------------------

RESPONSE
--------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 17:44:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Content-Encoding: gzip

8fc
...
```

Кракозябры в конце. Видимо из-за `Content-Encoding: gzip`... Посылаем такой же запрос, а ответ приходить другой.

Comment: Почему ваш "точно такой же" запрос из программы имеет на 1 заголовок больше?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Хорошо. Выходит, на запрос браузера сервер не кодирует страницу в gzip, а на мой - кодирует. Почему?

Comment: Я не в этом смысле. Браузер точно так же пишет. Мне в gzip приходит, а ему нет. Почему? Я об этом. Или Fiddler самовольно убирает поле Content-Encoding и добавдяет Content-Length на основе данных из тела пакета? Врят ли...

Answer (score 1):

Вы получили ответ в кодировке `chuncked`, о чем сервер и сообщает вам в ответе:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Подробнее как это работает, можно прочитать например в [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

---

Браузер сообщает серверу, что он умеет декодировать `gzip`:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

Поэтому сервер и присылает сжатый контент. В C# есть удобный класс `System.IO.Compression.GZipStream`, можете без проблем "разархивировать" сжатые данные.

Comment: Пожалуй, наиболее всего меня интересует принчина, по которой сервер отвечает по-разному на один и тот же запрос от браузера и от моей программы

Comment: Почему оветы различаются? Что позволило отличить это приложение от настоящего браузера?

Comment: @D.Stark В каком месте отличаются ответы? Fiddler автоматически сам расшифровывает gzip.

Comment: Я не вижу в ответе на мой запрос наличие поля Content-Length. Вместо него есть поле `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: @D.Stark Это странно. Я бы лучше не смотрел через фиддлер (может он что-то меняет), смотрите напрямую в браузере в Dev Tools.

Answer (score 1):

При передаче в режиме chunked перед каждым фрагментом передается его размер в шестнадцатеричном виде. Соответственно, вместо Content Length нужно использовать это значение.

> Браузер точно так же пишет. Мне в gzip приходит, а ему нет. Почему?

Когда вы указываете `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`, вы указываете предпочтительные форматы для передачи. Сервер может выбрать другой формат, если он считает сжатие нецелесообразным или из-за перегрузки не может его выполнять. Нет правила, что на один и тот же запрос в разные моменты времени должен придти один и тот же ответ.

Из https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding

> Even if both the client and the server supports the same compression
>   algorithms, the server may choose not to compress the body of a
>   response, if the identity value is also acceptable. Two common cases
>   lead to this:
>
> - The data to be sent is already compressed and a second compression won't lead to smaller data to be transmitted.
> - This may the case with some image formats; The server is overloaded and cannot afford the computational overhead induced by the
>     compression requirement. Typically, Microsoft recommends not to
>     compress if a server use more than 80 % of its computational power.

Чтобы явно требовать передачу со сжатием, нужно указать что-то такое:

```
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, *;q=0
```

Чтобы наоборот, требовать обязательной передачи без сжатия - такое:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity, *;q=0
```

Comment: Не могли бы помочь с [таким вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855991/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-windows/856454#856454)? Благодарю.